# Pi and Python - Cannot connect to SSL from Pi - works on Win7

Tags: raspbian, python, ethernet

I am using Tikona Broadband ISP in Bangalore,India. The ISP need the user to login using a web proxy.

This is how my Pi is connected:

The ethernet from ISP lands on the router and the Pi is connected to the router using ethernet.

I followed some python code as in the links below:

http://www.brijin.net/login-to-tikona/

None of the code is working as it is. I tried to change the code as well and the current code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import sys
import mechanize
import time
from optparse import OptionParser
import getpass

def Login(username,password):
    print ">>> trying to connect.."
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    response  = br.open('http://1.254.254.254')
    print ">>> ok"
    print ">>> " + br.title()
    #print response.geturl()
    #print ">>>"
    print ">>> redirecting to login.do"
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form.action = 'https://login.tikona.in/userportal/login.do?requesturi=http%3A%2F%2F1.254.254.254%2F&act=null'
    #br.form.action = 'https://login.tikona.in/userportal/?requesturi=http%3a%2f%2f1%2e254%2e254%2e254%2f&ip=10%2e26%2e188%2e24&mac=fc%3a75%3a16%3ad2%3ade%3a0a&nas=tikonabangalore-3205&requestip=1%2e254%2e254%2e254&sc=76851ca3f6df9c5feaa4ac5bddd9068d'
    br.form.method = 'POST'
    print ">>> submitting.."
    response = br.submit()
    print ">>> got response"
    print response.read()
    br.select_form(name="form1")
    br["username"] = username
    br["password"] = password
    br.find_control(name="type").value = ["2"]
    br.form.method="POST"
    print ">>> proceeding to login.."
    br.form.action="https://login.tikona.in/userportal/newlogin.do?phone=0"
    print ">>> loggin in..."
    print ">>> ok " 
    print ">>> " + br.title()
    response = br.submit()
    #response.get_data()
    print ""
    print 50 * "*"
    print ""
    print response.info()
    print 50 * "*"
    print ""
    #print response.read()

def Logout():
    print "Logging out.."
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    response = br.open('https://login.tikona.in/userportal/logout.do?svccat=1')
    print response.geturl()
    print response.info()
    print response.read()
def main():
    Login("XXXXXXXX","!@#$%&^%")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

However I could not connect to the login url from the code. If I open the browser in the Pi, I can connect to the web proxy and login successfully.

**UPDATE**

*I ran the code on my laptop (Windows 7 64 bit and Python 2.7.8 and it works fine*

I do not think that the python code is having any problem, as I can connect to other sites, but not to the web-proxy somehow. And I thought it might need some small change in configs, yet clueless.

Can someone help me?

Here is the detailed error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autologin.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "autologin.py", line 54, in main
    Login("XXXXXXXX","!@#$%&^%")
  File "autologin.py", line 12, in Login
    response  = br.open('http://1.254.254.254')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 204, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_http.py", line 441, in http_response
    "refresh", msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 221, in error
    result = apply(self._call_chain, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 571, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 193, in open
    response = urlopen(self, req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 344, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1170, in https_open
    return self.do_open(conn_factory, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1118, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

so the primary issue seems to be something related to be able to open `https` and the final error message is `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>`

Comment: I would just work out with `Fiddler` what data is getting posted where. Then use python to post a form that is the same to that location. But, maybe the proxy requires a cookie and that complicates things but still doable with allot more effort.

Comment: Hehe, No - It would be nice though :) Fiddler works on Windows. Install it on there, go the login page, turn on Fiddler logging, back to browser and login. Back to Fiddler. Look for the `POST` or `GET` data an examine it. Then rebuild the HTTP Request in Python on the Pi.

Comment: WHat's failing. Can you please explain a bit more because I am just going on a whim here based on my experience and not what is actually happening on your side.

Comment: Just added the error details. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You should change your title Pi cannot connect to SSL.

Comment: Have you changed the code of the scripts ? Perhaps pasting the full script that you're using would also help

Comment: @Kangkan I'd blank out the username/ password first.

Comment: I don't see the line `response = br.submit()` in the source code you have provided.  Did you provide the source code to `autologin.py`?

Comment: Question, have you tried this code on Windows/Mac and does it work there?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: I tried and see the code working perfectly on Win7. But still does not work on my Pi.